# Как перенести блок вправо? Html/css

Tags: css

Всех приветствую. Есть контейнер с максимальной шириной. И в нем два блока. Все это flex. Как это все передвинуть к концу экрана вправо? Justiny пробовал, не работает. Извиняюсь за тупые вопросы, я учусь[image: блок]

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под "то все передвинуть к концу экрана вправо", что именно Вы хотите передвинуть вправо? Предоставьте лучше ваш html код.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду левый блок "The Cabins" и второй блок от него изображение, тогда их обёртке задайте justify-content: space-between; и текст встанет с левой стороны как и стоял, а изображение сдвинется в самый край. Если же как вы сказали они оба должны переместиться в право, тогда justify-content: flex-end; . Их обёртка при этом должна быть width: 100%; - так как я сейчас вижу, что она растянута не на всю ширину экрана.

Answer (score 2):

Не волнуйтесь, не существует глупых вопросов, особенно когда вы учитесь. Давайте рассмотрим, как можно выравнять ваши блоки вправо в контейнере с максимальной шириной, используя CSS и flexbox.

Предположим, у вас есть следующая разметка HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Блок 1</div>
    <div class="block">Блок 2</div>
</div>
```

А CSS может выглядеть так:

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1000px; /* Максимальная ширина контейнера */
    display: flex; /* Используем flexbox для выравнивания внутренних блоков */
    justify-content: flex-end; /* Это свойство выравнивает блоки к концу контейнера (вправо) */
}

.block {
    margin: 10px; /* Добавьте отступы, если это необходимо */
    padding: 10px; /* Добавьте внутренний отступ, если это необходимо */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Добавьте границы для видимости блоков */
}
```

В этом примере `justify-content: flex-end;` в CSS определяет выравнивание блоков к концу контейнера (вправо).

Comment: Плюсик я поставил но вот есть ньюанс, вопрос старый

Comment: И глупые вопросы существуют. Достаточно посмотреть вопросы с отрицательным рейтингом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
   align-self: flex-end
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]